# Как подключить js (front-end) файлы к django?

Tags: javascript, django

Нужно подключить `js` файл к `django` проекту. Никак не мог найти годную информацию на этот счёт. На форумах я нашёл лишь устаревшую информацию, а в документации показано лишь как подключать картинки.

Comment: В документации показано как подключаться статические ресурсы. Нет никакой разницы в подключении картинок, стилей или скриптов.

Comment: то есть, через тег img можно подключить js?

Comment: или всё же стоит его заменить на script?

Comment: Судя по этим комментариям, вам стоит сначала разобраться с базовыми принципами работы web прежде, чем браться за Django.

Comment: спасибо. Немного поправил и все заработало

Comment: кстати, а есть ли какая-нибудь статья об этом?

Answer (score 1):

`<script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>`